# Range variable not working in VBA for ExportAsFixedFormat

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting a worksheet name as wsDR and a named range on that worksheet called "daily_report" as rngDR to use in the ExportAsFixedFormat. However, it does not seem to work when combined in the code i.e. wsDR.rngDR.ExportAsFixedFormat _ 'rest of the code.

When I replace rngDR with range("daily_report") the code, wsDR.range("daily_report").ExportAsFixedFormat the sub works but when I simply use rngDR it doesn't work.

```
Sub PDFProductionReport()
'PDF of current worksheet
Dim wsDR As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strTime As String
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim reportName As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim rngDR As Range

On Error GoTo errHandler

Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsDR = Sheets("Daily Report")
Set rngDR = Range("daily_report")
strTime = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") '_hhmm")

'get active workbook folder, if saved
strPath = Sheets("Library").Range("N11").Value
If strPath = "" Then
  strPath = wbA.Path 'Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

'replace spaces and periods in sheet name
reportName = "Production Report" 'Title of the report change here
strName = Replace(reportName, " ", "")
strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")

'create default name for savng file
strFile = strName & "_" & strTime & ".pdf"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile

'use can enter name and
' select folder for file
myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

'export to PDF if a folder was selected
If myFile <> "False" Then
    wsDR.rngDR.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True     
    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & myFile
End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is happening? `Not working` or `it does not seem to work` is kind of useless. You might consider qualifying the objects: `Set wsDR = wbA.Worksheets("Daily Report")` and `Set rngDR = wsDR.Range("daily_report")` and only use the range variable when exporting `rgnDR.Export...` i.e. `rngDR` cannot be a property or a method of `wsDR`.

Comment: Apologies, the error handling means that a message pops up and says no pdf created, so there was no real debug error that I could use to determine the issue. But thank you for the response, that worked using rngDR.Export...

Comment: A certain degree of accuracy is expected i.e. when you say *says no pdf created*, that is different than the actual showing message that says `"Could not create PDF file"` which means that your error-handling routine 'sprang into action'. To let the error happen, you could out-comment the line `On Error GoTo errHandler`. To have its number and description written to the Immediate window (*Ctrl+G*), you could e.g. add the following line to `errHandler` somewhere above its `Resume` line: `Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description`.